# How can I respec my character?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I have a tendency to regret my build after I start spending ability/skill points, which is why I appreciate when a game allows me to respec later on. There are just too many options to get things exactly right the first time. Will I be able to repec my abilities in Kingdoms of Amalur: Reckoning?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes you can.

You reset your skill trees by finding a Fate Weaver and paying a gold cost.  This will reset both your skills and abilities, though the cost will increase the more you use it.

One great point is that if you want to put the maximum amount of points towards your build, you'll need to respec at least once to redistribute the training points.

You can use this feature to do things like:

- Max out your detect hidden and go out and find all the Lorestones, then reset it down to a lower level (like for detecting chests only)
- Max out your alchemy to gain all the recipes then fateweave to a lower level.

I'm sure you can imagine many other uses for this.

Comment: That's a neat feature! Perfect for indecisive people like me :)

Comment: @spugsley I agree.  I don't mind running multiple characters, but I'd much prefer to concentrate my achievements and efforts on one character and explore the game (instead of relevelling and seeing the same game areas over)

Comment: Can both skills AND abilities be reset?

Comment: @Sterno To the best of my knowledge, yes, the Fateweaver will reset both.

Comment: It will even give you a free set of pants if you no longer meet equipment requirements, rather than simply leaving your character naked. How thoughtful!